# Exclude Domain in Exim config

Tags: php, email, cpanel, exim

We have been using exim through cpanel to send email this is because they support an SMTP relay to send email.

We have just moved over to Google Apps for our mail and we have a bit of a problem.

If you're on one of our websites and you have a mail script setup to send an email and that particular email is going to a domain that is hosted on the cPanel account, it won't send through the relay. It treats it as an internal email. I want it to go through the relay.

```
smart_route:
driver = manualroute
domains = !+local_domains
transport = remote_smtp_smtpauth
route_list = * smtp.sendgrid.net:587
```

I've tried removing the `domains = !+local_domains` line from the config and it seems to work. The only problem is that all emails that come to the server try to send again through to relay and it just gets stuck in a loop.

Is there away I can exclude a domain from the list so it will treat it as an external email address?

Comment: Do I just need to change the MX records for this one domain to a remove exchanger?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one. If you go to WHM > Edit DNS > example.com on the cPanel server where the account is located. At the bottom of the DNS editor screen is going to be a few options; Automatic, Remote, Local, and Backup.

You will want to change this to Remote. The reason for this is when the sendmail function is run is is sending on the server, so the server assumes that mail should be delivered locally. By changing the option to remote it forces the server to do a DNS lookup and deliver mail to Google's Servers.